# Error in onestrat(x[index, , drop = FALSE], clusters[index], nPSU[index][1], : Stratum (0) has only one PSU at stage 1

Tags: r, survey

i have a dataframe with information of participants' country, demographic characteristics (e.g. age, gender) and biochemical measurements (e.g. weight, bp readings etc). I also have the psu and weights calculated for each participant. i have:

```
steps_3jan <- STEPS_All_countries_4_ %>% select(country, year,
                                                age,
                                                sex,
                                                m11,
                                                m12,
                                                stratum,
                                                psu,
                                                wstep1,
                                                wstep2,
                                                wstep3)

steps_3jan <- subset(steps_3jan, !is.na(psu))
steps_3jan <- subset(steps_3jan, !is.na(wstep1))
steps_3jan <- subset(steps_3jan, !is.na(stratum))

steps_3jan_matrix <- as.data.frame(steps_3jan)
```

I was was trying to use svydesign to do this:

```
steps_3jan_design <- svydesign(id =~psu, 
                               strata =~stratum,
                               nest = TRUE,
                               weights = ~wstep1,
                               data = steps_3jan_matrix)

svymean(~age, steps_3jan_design, na.rm = TRUE)
```

but got the below error:

> Error in onestrat(x[index, , drop = FALSE], clusters[index], nPSU[index][1], : Stratum (0) has only one PSU at stage 1

if anyone is able to help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and provide your data using `dput(STEPS_All_countries_4_)`?

Comment: In particular, is it true that stratum 0 has only one PSU?